# Ubuntu 20.04 black screen despite updates

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, updates, reboot, secure-boot

I have installed the distro 20.04 before several months, it was working fine. Before one month I have updated it through the updater, and then, when I rebooted and then, there was a black screen with the choices, Ubuntu, ... and Windows (I have a dual device). To start Ubuntu normally leads to a totally black screen. I can only start Ubuntu advanced options and then in recovery mode. Every few days, I update again but despite that, it is impossible to start the Ubuntu normally.
My question is if there is a way to simply repair the system, or it is mandatory to reinstall it with an USB key.

Previously I tried to update and upgrade with the terminal by apt update and apt upgrade, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get to the terminal and something has not completed from before restart then.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

May complete it - and I've had that on two RYZEN CPU based p

Comment: I will try thank you

Comment: dpkg: error: unknown option -o

Comment: The option is -a and not -o                                                                                                                                                                                    sudo dpkg --configure -a                                                                                        Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages

Comment: I wrote -a, and the output is as I wrote in comment

Comment: Sometimes if its not shutting down you can ssh in and restart by force and or run that command. You can possibly boot into an older kernel and after a few complaints ctrl-alt-F2 until you get terminal prompt.